# Connecting RS232 GPS Board to Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, uart, rs232, ttl, gps

I purchased a NEO-6M GPS board to connect to my Raspberry Pi, and when I bought it I didn't realize that it was meant for RS-232 communication instead of UART TTL (which I believe is what the Raspberry Pi uses). I found an adapter which I think would work for connecting this. It is a USB to RS232/TTL cable which utilizes a PL2303HX chip. Looking at the datasheet for this chip though, it says it supports "RS232-like" communication, and it looks like it only lists 1.8v-3.3v as the supported I/O voltage range (however I may be reading the wrong value in the datasheet for this). The GPS board that I bought outputs -5.5v to +5.5v though for its I/O. I am confused because it seems like this adapter should work for RS232 communication but the voltages don't seem to match. Would it work or should I find another?

Edit: Here is the PL2303HX datasheet (which is inside the USB to RS232/TTL adapter): https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PL2303HX.pdf

Comment: Certainly you could purchase an RS232-USB adapter (one with a DE9 connector).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118354/discussion-on-question-by-awesomemariofan-connecting-rs232-gps-board-to-raspberr).